# Why doesn't the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch dependency include the Sniffer package?

Tags: spring-boot

Why doesn't the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch dependency include the Sniffer package? If you're using the RestHighLevelClient to connect to an Elasticsearch cluster, you're essentially required to use Sniffer to maintain the connection. For developers who are not familiar with the source code, this leads to a poor user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including Sniffer in the starter would enable it by default. That isn't a good idea as it isn't always useful.
This [Elasticsearch blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-sniffing-best-practices-what-when-why-how) describes sniffing as a "double-edged sword" and lists some reasons not to use it:

> There are many situations where sniffing could cause some issues, including:
>
> - The Elasticsearch user your client is authenticating with doesn’t have the right permissions (monitoring_user role) to access the nodes API.
> - You’re working with cloud providers.

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation. I don't understand it well enough.